# how to create wallet in mangopay?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, mangopay

I want to integrate mangopay using php and i am using following link as ref:
http://docs.mangopay.com/api-references/wallets/
but i can't able to do that because if i am use any options like create wallet or any other then it will try to create new user even i am trying to use any other option.

following is code which i used for create new wallet in mangopay:

```
<h2>Create User</h2>
<form action="https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com/v2/clients" method="post">
<input name="ClientId" id="ClientId" value="<cust's sandbox id>" /><br>
    <input name="Email" id="Email" value="" /><br>
    <input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="" /><br>
    <input name="LastName" id="LastName" value="" /><br>
    <input name="Birthday" id="Birthday" value="<?php echo strtotime("1988-03-19");?>" /><br>
    <input name="Nationality" id="Nationality" value="DE" /><br>
    <input name="CountryOfResidence" id="CountryOfResidence" value="DE" /><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<h2>Create Wallet</h2>
<form action="https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com/v2/clients" method="post">
    <input name="ClientId" id="ClientId" value="<cust's sandbox id>" /><br>
    <input name="Owners" id="Owners" value="<cust's sandbox id>" /><br>
    <input name="Email" id="Email   " value="mddipen" /><br>
    <input name="Description" id="Description" value="" /><br>
    <input name="Currency" id="Currency" value="EUR" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use mangopay with wordpress?

Comment: Try https://github.com/aleph1888/mangopay_edd_plugin_web

Comment: @Dipen, you should really consider using the official PHP SDK https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk :-) 
Especially since your code isn't safe at all - if you're allowing the user to see your ClientId/Passphrase in their browser - these infos are very sensitive and should only ever be used for server-server communication with Mangopay, not in your HTML!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('MANGOPAY_REQUEST_URL','https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com/v2/');
define('MANGOPAY_ADMIN_ID','Admin ID');
define('CURL_AUTH_HEADER','Authentication Key');

function processCurlJsonrequest($parseUrl, $fieldString) { //Initiate cURL request and send back the result
    $URL=MANGOPAY_REQUEST_URL.$parseUrl;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic ".CURL_AUTH_HEADER, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8","Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fieldString));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $resulta = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    return $resulta;
}

    $data = array(
        "FirstName" => $first_name,
        "LastName" => $last_name,
        "Address" => "",
        "Birthday" => $birthdatestr, 
        "Nationality" => $nationality,
        "CountryOfResidence" => $CountryOfResidence,
        "Occupation" => "", 
        "IncomeRange" => "", 
        "ProofOfIdentity" => null,
        "ProofOfAddress" => null, 
        //"PersonType" => "NATURAL", 
        "Email" => $email, 
        "Tag" => ""
    );      
    $parseUrl=MANGOPAY_ADMIN_ID.'/users/natural';
    $response= processCurlJsonrequest($parseUrl, $data);
    $arrResponse=json_decode($response);
    $mangopay_userId = $arrResponse->Id;

    $data_mangopay = array(
        "Owners" => array($mangopay_userId),
        "Description" => "A very cool wallet",
        "Currency" => "EUR",
        "Tag" => ""
    );                                                                  
    $parseUrl=MANGOPAY_ADMIN_ID.'/wallets';
    $response_mangopay= processCurlJsonrequest($parseUrl, $data_mangopay);
    $arrResponse_mangopay=json_decode($response_mangopay);
    $mangopay_walletId = $arrResponse_mangopay->Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what the problem is - are you trying to create a new user AND wallet on the same page? If so, that isn't possible - you'll have to get the UserId first to then supply for the wallet creation.
Also, if you're not yet using the new [PHP SDK](https://github.com/MangoPay/mangopay2-php-sdk), I suggest you do as it's really comprehensive. However the reference/docs are pretty dire but I found [this site](http://www.mangopay-api-reference.com/) which is very useful.

Using the SDK and to solve your problem if I've understood it correctly:

```
//Create an instance of MangoPayApi SDK
$mangoPayApi = new \MangoPay\MangoPayApi();
$mangoPayApi->Config->ClientId = MangoPayDemo_ClientId;
$mangoPayApi->Config->ClientPassword = MangoPayDemo_ClientPassword;
$mangoPayApi->Config->TemporaryFolder = MangoPayDemo_TemporaryFolder;

//Build the parameters for the request
$User = new MangoPay\User();
$User->PersonType = "NATURAL";
$User->FirstName = "blabla";
$User->LastName = "blabla";
$User->Address = "blabla";
$User->Birthday = 1396886568;
$User->Nationality = "NZ";
$User->CountryOfResidence = "ES";
$User->Email = "hello@example.com";

//Send the request
$createdUser = $mangoPayApi->Users->Create($User);

//Now for the wallet
$Wallet = new MangoPay\Wallet();
$Wallet->Owners = array($createdUser->Id);
$Wallet->Description = "blabla";
$Wallet->Currency = "GBP";

//Send the request
$createdWallet = $mangoPayApi->Wallets->Create($Wallet);
//store this in your DB: $createdWallet->Id
```